# how could I know if my phone's been hacked

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, whatsapp-messenger

Someone is telling me every single item of information that I sent via whatsapp

how could I know if it is my phone or only the whatsapp account has been hacked

I use Samsong Galaxy S4 Gt-I9500
android 5.0.1

Comment: Interesting. Is that _someone_ your friend, pulling a prank or is this serious?

Comment: Is your Wi-Fi network secure? Phone rooted? Whatsapp from Play Store?

Comment: Is that _someone_ spying on you in real-time or gets your messages later?

Comment: no it is serious

Comment: he is spying on me in real time and I downloaded whatsapp from the official site for whatsapp. and I don not know whether my wi-fi network is secure or not

Answer (score 1):

Check for the whatsapp web feature , from menu select "whatsapp web" , probably they got it authorized in your absence . And they can continue to access unless you log out or cookies are cleared.

you can logout from mobile app itself. choose "log out from all computers"

from home screen of whatsapp , click on the "more" menu "(three dots)" in the top right corner of screen. The drop down menu appears, there select "whatsapp web",
then there is list of sessions running, just choose "logout from all computers" under that list.

Comment: Can you please provide clear menu directions for logging out?

Comment: I did log out..

Comment: unfortunately nothing seemed to be work

Comment: he is still getting the messages from you? then apparently you need to check your mobile for spyware apps.

Comment: is there any antispy app you recomend?

Comment: somebody advise me to change the imei for my mobile.. he is a tecknician. but I don't know if that would really work!?

Comment: i don't think spy apps as such exists but, why not just factory reset your phone? it will flush out everything out of your phone. and changing imei is not recommended , it may leave your phone unusable with any cellular networks.